# Refresh CustomControl from class in WinForms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls, refresh

How can I refresh a Custom Control from a class in C#?
I need to do this, because I have got a class which draws my animations. Until now I use a timer to refresh my control every 10ms. But this is not 100% safe.

Comment: What technology do you use? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. I use WinForms

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx

There is stuff that says you should call `Refresh` on itself or parent control. You can put it to some container and call Refresh on it. But I won't reccomend this, because this will use much resources: item will be invalidated and with its children will be redrawn each 10ms (as you call Refresh). However, if you have algorithm, which will be optimized to redraw children selectively, then you can use Refresh.

Comment: So this means that i shoudlnt/cant call refresh from a class?